# Почему ymaps.geocode возвращает отличный результат от ymaps.control.SearchControl?

Tags: yandex-maps-api

Необходимо полулучить список объектов по адресу для создания подсказки за пределами карты:

```
ymaps.geocode(addressString, {
        results: 5,
        boundedBy: bounds,
        strictBounds: true
    }).then(function (res) {
    ...
```

Область поиска ограничена (в примере - Оренбургская область, набираем по букве населенный пункт 'Саракташ'), запросы уходят начиная с третьего символа, в итоге получаем:

metaData:

-- 3 символа --

```
geocoder:
found: 1
request: "Сар"
results: 5
skip: 0
suggest: undefined
```

-- 4 символа --

```
geocoder:
found: 6
request: "Сара"
results: 5
skip: 0
suggest: undefined
```

-- 5 символов --

```
found: 0
request: "Сарак"
results: 5
skip: 0
suggest: undefined
```

-- 6 символов --

```
found: 3
request: "Саракт"
results: 5
skip: 0
suggest: Array(2)
0: "Саракт"
1: ["аш"]
```

То есть, до 6 символов либо ничего не найдено (при пяти символах нулевой ответ), либо если есть, но не те. Изменение ограничения результатов с 5 до 10 не приводит к результату с нужным населенным пунктом.

Если использовать контрол **ymaps.control.SearchControl**, то 'Саракташ' начинает находиться со второго символа. (Нет особой разницы, какой вводить населенный пункт)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Геокодер это отдельный инструмент, и его задача вернуть наиболее подходящий объект. А SearchPanel - это комплексный элемент, включающий в себя в том числе метод suggest. Если вам нужны только подсказки, вам нужен метод [suggest](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/suggest-docpage/)
2. [Отключение](https://tech.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/2.1/ref/reference/control.SearchControl-docpage/#control.SearchControl__param-parameters.options.noSuggestPanel) подсказок в элементе поиска.